# SharePoint 2007 Custom Sorting for Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a uploaded slides from PowerPoint to a document library that can then be collected for a staff meeting presentation. Each slide has its own number and place where it belongs for the slideshow. When I add a new slide, SP automatically puts the new slide at the end of the document library which is fine, but I want to be able to change the slide number and have it automatically go to the correct spot in the presentation without having multiple slides have the same slide number. If I want the new slide to be number 2 but there is already a slide that says it is number 2, the current slide should switch to 3 along with the rest changing to their perspective spots/numbers in the presentation. Is there an automatic way to do this without manually editing each slide property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm rusty but:

1. Create custom column for the document library
2. Add an event receiver (itemAdded), written in C# to the document library. When an item is added, programmatically find the slide number (this might not be easy...). Alternatively just have the user enter the slide number on the column (e.g. make it visible)
3. Create a view that's sorted by your new custom column

As for having multiple slides with the same number, I don't know how you'd handle that. You'd probably have to write your own sorting algorithm for the document library but IDK how and I don't have time to research it for you, sorry. Otherwise you could "fake it" by programmatically handling it in your event receiver. By the way, sharepoint.stackexchange.com would be a better site for this question.